# Which model and distribution to use to fit continuous proportional data with random effects; glmmTMB, glmer, lme? I am getting errors with all 3

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, glmmtmb

I am having trouble determining the most appropriate model to fit my continuous proportional data. I am analysing the proportion of time individuals were detected within an acoustic receiver array over 10 years. All data is between 0-1. The number of individuals differed across years (i.e. individual is random)
Response= Proportion,
Predictors = Year * Month,
Random effect = Tag.ID,
Need to also consider autocorrelation.

I am trying to decide between  `family = binomial` or `family = beta` and also whether to use lme, glmmTMB, glmer, but keep getting errors.

1. **lme** with arcsine transformed response variable

```
res.ind.lme = lme(transf.arcsin(Prop) ~ Year * Mon, 
                  random = ~1|Tag.ID, 
                  data=df, 
                  method = 'REML')
```

> Error:Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) :  Singularity in
> backsolve at level 0, block 1

2. **glmmTMB** with a beta distribution and logit link

```
res.ind.glmmTMB = glmmTMB(Prop ~ Year * Mon + (1|Tag.ID), 
                          df, 
                          family=list(family="beta",link="logit"), 
                          control = glmmTMBControl(), 
                          REML='TRUE')
```

> Error: plain list is deprecatedNA/NaN function evaluation
> Error in (function (start, objective, gradient = NULL, hessian = NULL: gradient
> function must return a numeric vector of length 2

3. ** **glmer****

```
res.ind.glmer = glmer(Prop ~ Position * Time.Period + (1|Tag.ID), 
                      data=df, 
                      family=binomial, 
                      weight=Total.Det)
```

> Error: non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!Model failed to converge with >max|grad| = 0.00455048 (tol = 0.002, component 1)

I have done a lot of reading and am just confusing myself, so any advice or reading recommendations are greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are the proportions calculated ? In a binomial model you typically have a number of "successes" out of a total number of indepent "trials" (ie the binomial distribution) so  it is common to use `glmer( cbind(success, failure) ~ var1 + ..., family=binomial`, where the `success / (success + failure)` is often the poportion that you are considering as as the outcome, although weights are another way to do it.

Comment: Hi @RobertLong thanks for your response. The proportions are calculated by dividing the number of detections per individual per month by the total number of receivers in an array to obtain what is known as a 'residency index' between 0 - 1. The 'weight' in this case is the total number of detections for each individual across the course of the study.

Comment: Ok so that should be equivalent. What happens when you use cbind without the weights ?

Comment: OK, I have used cbind() in my model here;

prop.glmer = glmer(cbind(Detection.Index, Number.of.Detections) ~ Year + Season + (1|Tag.ID), data=df, family=binomial)

And receiver this error about failure to converge. I am also unable to test for the interaction between Year * Season because of failure to converge.

Error:
"non-integer counts in a binomial glm!failure to converge in 10000 evaluationsunable to evaluate scaled gradientModel failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues"

Comment: Following on from this I have also tried this model:

res.ind.glmer1 = glmer(Detection.Index ~ Year + Season + (1|Tag.ID), data=det.sum.kbay.mon, family=binomial)

And receive this error:Error in pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tol = tolPwrss, GQmat = GQmat, compDev = compDev, : Downdated VtV is not positive definite

Comment: How many levels of `Tag.ID` do you have, and are you sure that the `Prop ` varies within those levels ?

Comment: I have 12 levels of Tag.ID and yes, prop varies between each level. There is not a huge amount of variation, but there is some. Could this error be caused by the fact some Tag.IDs are not present in all years or months? E.g. There was only 1 shark in 2010, 3 in 2013, 5 in 2014. So for some Years and Seasons Prop will be NA? These data are obviously not included in the dataframe.